# Iterating over directory to create dataframe

Tags: python

I have a directory with several files and a function that looks like this (Python 3.9):

```
  def dataframer(directory):
    file_list = []
    for file in os.listdir(directory):
        filename = os.fsdecode(file)
        if filename.endswith('csv'):
            file_list.append(filename)
    #print(file_list)
            dfs = {f"{file}_df" for file in file_list}
    #print(dfs)
            for d in dfs:
                frames = [f'{d} = pd.read_csv(f"interim_26/{file}", sep=";", header=[0])' for d in dfs]
            for el in frames:
                print(el)
```

Upon executing said function, I receive this output:

```
ch_01.csv_df = pd.read_csv(f"interim_26/Vorrede.csv", sep=";", header=[0])
ch_07.csv_df = pd.read_csv(f"interim_26/Vorrede.csv", sep=";", header=[0])
ch_14.csv_df = pd.read_csv(f"interim_26/Vorrede.csv", sep=";", header=[0])
ch_15.csv_df = pd.read_csv(f"interim_26/Vorrede.csv", sep=";", header=[0])
ch_16.csv_df = pd.read_csv(f"interim_26/Vorrede.csv", sep=";", header=[0])
ch_22.csv_df = pd.read_csv(f"interim_26/Vorrede.csv", sep=";", header=[0])
ch_20.csv_df = pd.read_csv(f"interim_26/Vorrede.csv", sep=";", header=[0])
ch_18.csv_df = pd.read_csv(f"interim_26/Vorrede.csv", sep=";", header=[0])
ch_25.csv_df = pd.read_csv(f"interim_26/Vorrede.csv", sep=";", header=[0])
ch_04.csv_df = pd.read_csv(f"interim_26/Vorrede.csv", sep=";", header=[0])
ch_11.csv_df = pd.read_csv(f"interim_26/Vorrede.csv", sep=";", header=[0])
ch_19.csv_df = pd.read_csv(f"interim_26/Vorrede.csv", sep=";", header=[0])
ch_21.csv_df = pd.read_csv(f"interim_26/Vorrede.csv", sep=";", header=[0])
ch_06.csv_df = pd.read_csv(f"interim_26/Vorrede.csv", sep=";", header=[0])
ch_26.csv_df = pd.read_csv(f"interim_26/Vorrede.csv", sep=";", header=[0])
ch_12.csv_df = pd.read_csv(f"interim_26/Vorrede.csv", sep=";", header=[0])
ch_09.csv_df = pd.read_csv(f"interim_26/Vorrede.csv", sep=";", header=[0])
ch_05.csv_df = pd.read_csv(f"interim_26/Vorrede.csv", sep=";", header=[0])
ch_03.csv_df = pd.read_csv(f"interim_26/Vorrede.csv", sep=";", header=[0])
schluss.csv_df = pd.read_csv(f"interim_26/Vorrede.csv", sep=";", header=[0])
ch_10.csv_df = pd.read_csv(f"interim_26/Vorrede.csv", sep=";", header=[0])
ch_02.csv_df = pd.read_csv(f"interim_26/Vorrede.csv", sep=";", header=[0])
ch_24.csv_df = pd.read_csv(f"interim_26/Vorrede.csv", sep=";", header=[0])
ch_08.csv_df = pd.read_csv(f"interim_26/Vorrede.csv", sep=";", header=[0])
ch_17.csv_df = pd.read_csv(f"interim_26/Vorrede.csv", sep=";", header=[0])
ch_13.csv_df = pd.read_csv(f"interim_26/Vorrede.csv", sep=";", header=[0])
Vorrede.csv_df = pd.read_csv(f"interim_26/Vorrede.csv", sep=";", header=[0])
ch_23.csv_df = pd.read_csv(f"interim_26/Vorrede.csv", sep=";", header=[0])

Process finished with exit code 1
```

You can probably guess, what I want:

I want every ch_{no} to receive an entry that looks like

```
ch_01_csv_df = pd.read_csv(f"interim_26/ch_01", sep=";", header=[0] # and so forth
```

In a second step, I need every string to be executed as a pd.read_csv , how would I go about that?

All the best,
K

Comment: How about not generating a string that looks like a function call, but just calling the function?

Comment: via exec() somehow? can u please give an example?

Comment: just call the function instead of formatting it as a string and putting it in a dictionary: `for d in dfs:  pd.read_csv(f"interim_26/{file}", sep=";", header=[0])`

Comment: Take the line `file_list.append(filename)` as an example. You didn't write `s = f'file_list.append({filename})'` and then `exec(s)` or something like that, either.

Comment: thanks, I think I was too deep in the code :-D 
If you post it as an answer, I'll mark it as one :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What the others in the comments try to tell you. If you have lots of filenames and you want to loop through and create dataframes, you don't need to build a f-string with the function call. Only create the path with file and call the function `pd.read_csv`

```
 def dataframer(directory):
    file_list = []
    dict_of_dfs = {}
    for file in os.listdir(directory):
        filename = os.fsdecode(file)
        if filename.endswith('csv'):
            file_list.append(filename)
    for file in file_list:
        dict_of_dfs[f"{file}_df"]=pd.read_csv(f"interim_26/{file}",sep=";",header=[0])
```

this should give you a dictionary where you have a dataFrame to every key